# fatal error: Geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped.h directory not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i tried to use this Github File: https://github.com/ros-drivers/um7.git
i used git clone to download it, changed the CMakeLists.txt and tried the Command catkin_make.  But it doesnt work i get the fatal Error back. I used already the geometry_msgs/Vector3 without problems but Vector3Stamped doesnt work... is there any Library to replace it ? or do anybody have a tip what i can Install to let it work ?

i use a Raspberry Pi4, Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) and Ros Noetic

i added the first the Error output, then the changes in the CMakeLists.txt and then the  complete cpp File here :

**Error if i let geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped.h active :**

### /home/ubuntu/um7_driver/src/um7/src/main.cpp:37:10: fatal error: geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped.h: No such file or directory
37 | #include "geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped.h"
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/um7_driver_2.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/um7_driver_2.dir/um7/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1097: CMakeFiles/um7_driver_2.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  1%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  1%] Built target _actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GoalStatus
[  1%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_TopicInfo
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

**Error if i comment geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped out:**

/home/ubuntu/um7_driver/src/um7/src/main.cpp:38:10: fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory
38 | #include "ros/ros.h"
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/um7_driver_2.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/um7_driver_2.dir/um7/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1097: CMakeFiles/um7_driver_2.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  1%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  1%] Built target _actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GoalID
[  1%] Built target _actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_GoalStatusArray
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

**Changes in CMakeLists.txt :**

catkin_workspace()

include_directories( ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable( um7_driver_2 /home/ubuntu/um7_driver/src/um7/src/main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( um7_driver_2 ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )

---

the new CMakeLists.txt:

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(um7_test)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp serial sensor_msgs message_generation)

add_service_files(
FILES
Reset.srv
)

generate_messages()

catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
)

###########

### Build

###########

### Specify additional locations of header files

### Your package locations should be listed before other locations

include_directories(include
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

### Declare a cpp executable

add_executable(um7_driver src/main.cpp src/registers.cpp src/comms.cpp)
target_link_libraries(um7_driver ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
add_dependencies(um7_driver um7_generate_messages_cpp)

#############

### Install

#############

install(TARGETS um7_driver
RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

#############

### Testing

#############
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
find_package(roslint REQUIRED)
catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}_test_registers test/test_registers.cpp src/registers.cpp)
  catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}_test_comms test/test_comms.cpp src/comms.cpp src/registers.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_test_comms util ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

file(GLOB LINT_SRCS
src/*.cpp
include/um7/registers.h
include/um7/comms.h)
roslint_cpp(${LINT_SRCS})
roslint_add_test()
endif()

include_directories( ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable( um7_driver_2 /home/ubuntu/um7_driver/src/um7/src/main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( um7_driver_2 ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )

---

**Complete cpp File main.cpp:**

/**
*

- \file
- \brief      Main entry point for UM7 driver. Handles serial connection
- ```
           details, as well as all ROS message stuffing, parameters,
  ```
- ```
           topics, etc.
  ```
- \author     Mike Purvis mpurvis@clearpathrobotics.com (original code for UM6)
- \copyright  Copyright (c) 2013, Clearpath Robotics, Inc.
- \author     Alex Brown rbirac@cox.net         (adapted to UM7)
- \copyright  Copyright (c) 2015, Alex Brown.
- 
- 

*/
#include 
#include "geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped.h"
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "sensor_msgs/Imu.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/MagneticField.h"
#include "serial/serial.h"
#include "std_msgs/Float32.h"
#include "std_msgs/Header.h"
#include "um7/comms.h"
#include "um7/registers.h"
#include "um7/Reset.h"

const char VERSION[10] = "0.0.2";   // um7_driver version

// Don't try to be too clever. Arrival of this message triggers
// us to publish everything we have.
const uint8_t TRIGGER_PACKET = DREG_EULER_PHI_THETA;

namespace OutputAxisOptions
{
enum OutputAxisOption
{
DEFAULT, ENU, ROBOT_FRAME
};
}
typedef OutputAxisOptions::OutputAxisOption OutputAxisOption;

/**

- Function generalizes the process of writing an XYZ vector into consecutive
- fields in UM7 registers.
  */
  template
  void configureVector3(um7::Comms* sensor, const um7::Accessor& reg,
  std::string param, std::string human_name)
  {
  if (reg.length != 3)
  {
  throw std::logic_error("configureVector3 may only be used with 3-field registers!");
  }

if (ros::param::has(param))
{
double x, y, z;
ros::param::get(param + "/x", x);
ros::param::get(param + "/y", y);
ros::param::get(param + "/z", z);
ROS_INFO_STREAM("Configuring " << human_name << " to ("
<< x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")");
reg.set_scaled(0, x);
reg.set_scaled(1, y);
reg.set_scaled(2, z);
if (sensor->sendWaitAck(reg))
{
throw std::runtime_error("Unable to configure vector.");
}
}
}

/**

- Function generalizes the process of commanding the UM7 via one of its command
- registers.
  */
  template
  void sendCommand(um7::Comms* sensor, const um7::Accessor& reg, std::string human_name)
  {
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Sending command: " << human_name);
  if (!sensor->sendWaitAck(reg))
  {
  throw std::runtime_error("Command to device failed.");
  }
  }

/**

- Send configuration messages to the UM7, critically, to turn on the value outputs
- which we require, and inject necessary configuration parameters.
  */
  void configureSensor(um7::Comms* sensor, ros::NodeHandle *private_nh)
  {
  um7::Registers r;

uint32_t comm_reg = (BAUD_115200 << COM_BAUD_START);
r.communication.set(0, comm_reg);
if (!sensor->sendWaitAck(r.comrate2))
{
throw std::runtime_error("Unable to set CREG_COM_SETTINGS.");
}

// set the broadcast rate of the device
int rate;
private_nh->param("update_rate", rate, 20);
if (rate < 20 || rate > 255)
{
ROS_WARN("Potentially unsupported update rate of %d", rate);
}

uint32_t rate_bits = static_cast<uint32_t>(rate);
ROS_INFO("Setting update rate to %uHz", rate);
uint32_t raw_rate = (rate_bits << RATE2_ALL_RAW_START);
r.comrate2.set(0, raw_rate);
if (!sensor->sendWaitAck(r.comrate2))
{
throw std::runtime_error("Unable to set CREG_COM_RATES2.");
}

uint32_t proc_rate = (rate_bits << RATE4_ALL_PROC_START);
r.comrate4.set(0, proc_rate);
if (!sensor->sendWaitAck(r.comrate4))
{
throw std::runtime_error("Unable to set CREG_COM_RATES4.");
}

uint32_t misc_rate = (rate_bits << RATE5_EULER_START) | (rate_bits << RATE5_QUAT_START);
r.comrate5.set(0, misc_rate);
if (!sensor->sendWaitAck(r.comrate5))
{
throw std::runtime_error("Unable to set CREG_COM_RATES5.");
}

uint32_t health_rate = (5 << RATE6_HEALTH_START);  // note:  5 gives 2 hz rate
r.comrate6.set(0, health_rate);
if (!sensor->sendWaitAck(r.comrate6))
{
throw std::runtime_error("Unable to set CREG_COM_RATES6.");
}

// Options available using parameters)
uint32_t misc_config_reg = 0;  // initialize all options off

// Optionally disable mag updates in the sensor's EKF.
bool mag_updates;
private_nh->param("mag_updates", mag_updates, true);
if (mag_updates)
{
misc_config_reg |= MAG_UPDATES_ENABLED;
}
else
{
ROS_WARN("Excluding magnetometer updates from EKF.");
}

// Optionally enable quaternion mode .
bool quat_mode;
private_nh->param("quat_mode", quat_mode, true);
if (quat_mode)
{
misc_config_reg |= QUATERNION_MODE_ENABLED;
}
else
{
ROS_WARN("Excluding quaternion mode.");
}

r.misc_config.set(0, misc_config_reg);
if (!sensor->sendWaitAck(r.misc_config))
{
throw std::runtime_error("Unable to set CREG_MISC_SETTINGS.");
}

// Optionally disable performing a zero gyros command on driver startup.
bool zero_gyros;
private_nh->param("zero_gyros", zero_gyros, true);
if (zero_gyros) sendCommand(sensor, r.cmd_zero_gyros, "zero gyroscopes");
}

bool handleResetService(um7::Comms* sensor,
const um7::Reset::Request& req, const um7::Reset::Response& resp)
{
um7::Registers r;
if (req.zero_gyros) sendCommand(sensor, r.cmd_zero_gyros, "zero gyroscopes");
if (req.reset_ekf) sendCommand(sensor, r.cmd_reset_ekf, "reset EKF");
if (req.set_mag_ref) sendCommand(sensor, r.cmd_set_mag_ref, "set magnetometer reference");
return true;
}

/**

- Uses the register accessors to grab data from the IMU, and populate
- the ROS messages which are output.
  */
  void publishMsgs(um7::Registers& r, ros::NodeHandle* imu_nh, sensor_msgs::Imu& imu_msg,
  OutputAxisOption axes, bool use_magnetic_field_msg)
  {
  static ros::Publisher imu_pub = imu_nh->advertise<sensor_msgs::Imu>("data", 1, false);
  static ros::Publisher mag_pub;
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  if (use_magnetic_field_msg)
  {
  mag_pub = imu_nh->advertise<sensor_msgs::MagneticField>("mag", 1, false);
  }
  else
  {
  cout<<"Vector3Stamped";
  mag_pub = imu_nh->advertise<geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped>("mag", 1, false);
  }
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  static ros::Publisher rpy_pub = imu_nh->advertise<geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped>("rpy", 1, false);
  static ros::Publisher temp_pub = imu_nh->advertise<std_msgs::Float32>("temperature", 1, false);

if (imu_pub.getNumSubscribers() > 0)
{
switch (axes)
{
case OutputAxisOptions::ENU:
{
// body-fixed frame NED to ENU: (x y z)->(x -y -z) or (w x y z)->(x -y -z w)
// world frame      NED to ENU: (x y z)->(y  x -z) or (w x y z)->(y  x -z w)
// world frame
imu_msg.orientation.w =  r.quat.get_scaled(2);
imu_msg.orientation.x =  r.quat.get_scaled(1);
imu_msg.orientation.y = -r.quat.get_scaled(3);
imu_msg.orientation.z =  r.quat.get_scaled(0);

```
    // body-fixed frame
    imu_msg.angular_velocity.x =  r.gyro.get_scaled(0);
    imu_msg.angular_velocity.y = -r.gyro.get_scaled(1);
    imu_msg.angular_velocity.z = -r.gyro.get_scaled(2);

    // body-fixed frame
    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.x =  r.accel.get_scaled(0);
    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.y = -r.accel.get_scaled(1);
    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.z = -r.accel.get_scaled(2);
    break;
  }
  case OutputAxisOptions::ROBOT_FRAME:
  {
    // body-fixed frame
    imu_msg.orientation.w = -r.quat.get_scaled(0);
    imu_msg.orientation.x = -r.quat.get_scaled(1);
    imu_msg.orientation.y =  r.quat.get_scaled(2);
    imu_msg.orientation.z =  r.quat.get_scaled(3);

    // body-fixed frame
    imu_msg.angular_velocity.x =  r.gyro.get_scaled(0);
    imu_msg.angular_velocity.y = -r.gyro.get_scaled(1);
    imu_msg.angular_velocity.z = -r.gyro.get_scaled(2);

    // body-fixed frame
    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.x =  r.accel.get_scaled(0);
    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.y = -r.accel.get_scaled(1);
    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.z = -r.accel.get_scaled(2);
    break;
  }
  case OutputAxisOptions::DEFAULT:
  {
    imu_msg.orientation.w = r.quat.get_scaled(0);
    imu_msg.orientation.x = r.quat.get_scaled(1);
    imu_msg.orientation.y = r.quat.get_scaled(2);
    imu_msg.orientation.z = r.quat.get_scaled(3);

    imu_msg.angular_velocity.x = r.gyro.get_scaled(0);
    imu_msg.angular_velocity.y = r.gyro.get_scaled(1);
    imu_msg.angular_velocity.z = r.gyro.get_scaled(2);

    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.x = r.accel.get_scaled(0);
    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.y = r.accel.get_scaled(1);
    imu_msg.linear_acceleration.z = r.accel.get_scaled(2);
    break;
  }
  default:
    ROS_ERROR("OuputAxes enum value invalid");
}

imu_pub.publish(imu_msg);
```

}

// Magnetometer.  transform to ROS axes
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (mag_pub.getNumSubscribers() > 0)
{
if (use_magnetic_field_msg)
{
sensor_msgs::MagneticField mag_msg;
mag_msg.header = imu_msg.header;

```
  switch (axes)
  {
    case OutputAxisOptions::ENU:
    {
      mag_msg.magnetic_field.x = r.mag.get_scaled(1);
      mag_msg.magnetic_field.y = r.mag.get_scaled(0);
      mag_msg.magnetic_field.z = -r.mag.get_scaled(2);
      break;
    }
    case OutputAxisOptions::ROBOT_FRAME:
    {
      // body-fixed frame
      mag_msg.magnetic_field.x =  r.mag.get_scaled(0);
      mag_msg.magnetic_field.y = -r.mag.get_scaled(1);
      mag_msg.magnetic_field.z = -r.mag.get_scaled(2);
      break;
    }
    case OutputAxisOptions::DEFAULT:
    {
      mag_msg.magnetic_field.x = r.mag.get_scaled(0);
      mag_msg.magnetic_field.y = r.mag.get_scaled(1);
      mag_msg.magnetic_field.z = r.mag.get_scaled(2);
      break;
    }
    default:
      ROS_ERROR("OuputAxes enum value invalid");
  }

  mag_pub.publish(mag_msg);
}
else
{
cout<<"Vector3Stamped";
  geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped mag_msg;
  mag_msg.header = imu_msg.header;

  switch (axes)
  {
    case OutputAxisOptions::ENU:
    {
      mag_msg.vector.x = r.mag.get_scaled(1);
      mag_msg.vector.y = r.mag.get_scaled(0);
      mag_msg.vector.z = -r.mag.get_scaled(2);
      break;
    }
    case OutputAxisOptions::ROBOT_FRAME:
    {
      // body-fixed frame
      mag_msg.vector.x =  r.mag.get_scaled(0);
      mag_msg.vector.y = -r.mag.get_scaled(1);
      mag_msg.vector.z = -r.mag.get_scaled(2);
      break;
    }
    case OutputAxisOptions::DEFAULT:
    {
      mag_msg.vector.x = r.mag.get_scaled(0);
      mag_msg.vector.y = r.mag.get_scaled(1);
      mag_msg.vector.z = r.mag.get_scaled(2);
      break;

    }
    default:
      ROS_ERROR("OuputAxes enum value invalid");
  }

  mag_pub.publish(mag_msg);
}
```

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Euler attitudes.  transform to ROS axes
if (rpy_pub.getNumSubscribers() > 0)
{
geometry_msgs::Vector3Stamped rpy_msg;
rpy_msg.header = imu_msg.header;

```
switch (axes)
{
  case OutputAxisOptions::ENU:
  {
    // world frame
    rpy_msg.vector.x = r.euler.get_scaled(1);
    rpy_msg.vector.y = r.euler.get_scaled(0);
    rpy_msg.vector.z = -r.euler.get_scaled(2);
    break;
  }
  case OutputAxisOptions::ROBOT_FRAME:
  {
    rpy_msg.vector.x =  r.euler.get_scaled(0);
    rpy_msg.vector.y = -r.euler.get_scaled(1);
    rpy_msg.vector.z = -r.euler.get_scaled(2);
    break;
  }
  case OutputAxisOptions::DEFAULT:
  {
    rpy_msg.vector.x = r.euler.get_scaled(0);
    rpy_msg.vector.y = r.euler.get_scaled(1);
    rpy_msg.vector.z = r.euler.get_scaled(2);
    break;
  }
  default:
    ROS_ERROR("OuputAxes enum value invalid");
}

rpy_pub.publish(rpy_msg);
```

}

// Temperature
if (temp_pub.getNumSubscribers() > 0)
{
std_msgs::Float32 temp_msg;
temp_msg.data = r.temperature.get_scaled(0);
temp_pub.publish(temp_msg);
}
}

/**

- Node entry-point. Handles ROS setup, and serial port connection/reconnection.
  */
  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  ros::init(argc, argv, "um7_driver");

// Load parameters from private node handle.
std::string port;
int32_t baud;

ros::NodeHandle imu_nh("imu"), private_nh("~");
private_nh.paramstd::string("port", port, "/dev/ttyUSB0");
private_nh.param<int32_t>("baud", baud, 115200);

serial::Serial ser;
ser.setPort(port);
ser.setBaudrate(baud);
serial::Timeout to = serial::Timeout(50, 50, 0, 50, 0);
ser.setTimeout(to);

sensor_msgs::Imu imu_msg;
double linear_acceleration_stdev, angular_velocity_stdev;
private_nh.paramstd::string("frame_id", imu_msg.header.frame_id, "imu_link");
// Defaults obtained experimentally from hardware, no device spec exists
private_nh.param("linear_acceleration_stdev", linear_acceleration_stdev, (4.0 * 1e-3f * 9.80665));
private_nh.param("angular_velocity_stdev", angular_velocity_stdev, (0.06 * 3.14159 / 180.0));

double linear_acceleration_cov = linear_acceleration_stdev * linear_acceleration_stdev;
double angular_velocity_cov = angular_velocity_stdev * angular_velocity_stdev;

// From the UM7 datasheet for the dynamic accuracy from the EKF.
double orientation_x_stdev, orientation_y_stdev, orientation_z_stdev;
private_nh.param("orientation_x_stdev", orientation_x_stdev, (3.0 * 3.14159 / 180.0));
private_nh.param("orientation_y_stdev", orientation_y_stdev, (3.0 * 3.14159 / 180.0));
private_nh.param("orientation_z_stdev", orientation_z_stdev, (5.0 * 3.14159 / 180.0));

double orientation_x_covar = orientation_x_stdev * orientation_x_stdev;
double orientation_y_covar = orientation_y_stdev * orientation_y_stdev;
double orientation_z_covar = orientation_z_stdev * orientation_z_stdev;

// Enable converting from NED to ENU by default
bool tf_ned_to_enu;
bool orientation_in_robot_frame;
private_nh.param("tf_ned_to_enu", tf_ned_to_enu, true);
private_nh.param("orientation_in_robot_frame", orientation_in_robot_frame, false);
OutputAxisOption axes = OutputAxisOptions::DEFAULT;
if (tf_ned_to_enu && orientation_in_robot_frame)
{
ROS_ERROR("Requested IMU data in two separate frames.");
}
else if (tf_ned_to_enu)
{
axes = OutputAxisOptions::ENU;
}
else if (orientation_in_robot_frame)
{
axes = OutputAxisOptions::ROBOT_FRAME;
}

// Use MagneticField message rather than Vector3Stamped.
bool use_magnetic_field_msg;
private_nh.param("use_magnetic_field_msg", use_magnetic_field_msg, false);

// These values do not need to be converted
imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[0] = linear_acceleration_cov;
imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[4] = linear_acceleration_cov;
imu_msg.linear_acceleration_covariance[8] = linear_acceleration_cov;

imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[0] = angular_velocity_cov;
imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[4] = angular_velocity_cov;
imu_msg.angular_velocity_covariance[8] = angular_velocity_cov;

imu_msg.orientation_covariance[0] = orientation_x_covar;
imu_msg.orientation_covariance[4] = orientation_y_covar;
imu_msg.orientation_covariance[8] = orientation_z_covar;

// Real Time Loop
bool first_failure = true;
while (ros::ok())
{
try
{
ser.open();
}
catch (const serial::IOException& e)
{
ROS_WARN("um7_driver was unable to connect to port %s.", port.c_str());
}
if (ser.isOpen())
{
ROS_INFO("um7_driver successfully connected to serial port %s.", port.c_str());
first_failure = true;
try
{
um7::Comms sensor(&ser);
configureSensor(&sensor, &private_nh);
um7::Registers registers;
ros::ServiceServer srv = imu_nh.advertiseService<um7::Reset::Request, um7::Reset::Response>(
"reset", boost::bind(handleResetService, &sensor, _1, _2));

```
    while (ros::ok())
    {
      // triggered by arrival of last message packet
      if (sensor.receive(&registers) == TRIGGER_PACKET)
      {
        // Triggered by arrival of final message in group.
        imu_msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
        publishMsgs(registers, &imu_nh, imu_msg, axes, use_magnetic_field_msg);
        ros::spinOnce();
      }
    }
  }
  catch(const std::exception& e)
  {
    if (ser.isOpen()) ser.close();
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM(e.what());
    ROS_INFO("Attempting reconnection after error.");
    ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
  }
}
else
{
  ROS_WARN_STREAM_COND(first_failure, "Could not connect to serial device "
                       << port << ". Trying again every 1 second.");
  first_failure = false;
  ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
}
```

}
}whole

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381640/fatal-error:-geometry_msgs/vector3stamped.h-directory-not-found/) by [Fxaxo](https://answers.ros.org/users/75761/fxaxo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [photon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28317/photon/) on 2021-07-03**:
Could you include the compilation log, and the changes that was made in the `CMakeLists.txt`?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-03**:
@Fxaxo: Some friendly advice: you need to pay more attention to the format of file names: the first letter of `geometry_msgs` is not capitialized, and the first letter of `Vector3Stamped.h` is capitalized.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-05**:
@Fxaxo Please don't create an "answer" unless you are telling us what the solution to the title of this post is. Additional information like you posted below should be added as a comment (like this one.) Please delete that answer and instead put the new info into a comment.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-05**:
The line in which you include ros.h is not valid c. Also, please show us the exact text of the error from `catkin_make`.

**Comment by [Fxaxo](https://answers.ros.org/users/75761/fxaxo/) on 2021-07-05**:
oh okaz i understand ! okaz i postet the error output in the question. i already tried to install some sudo apt-get plug ins like ros-roscpp-msg to work with the ros library but it still not work... also with the geometry_msgs i installed already the ros-geometry-msgs

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-05**:
I suspect you are missing required lines in `CMakeLists.txt`. Have you provided lines with the necessary `roscpp` info? There are many, many examples of `CMakeLists.txt` for you to look at.

**Comment by [Fxaxo](https://answers.ros.org/users/75761/fxaxo/) on 2021-07-05**:
hm i compared my CMakeLists to many others who using the lib ros/ros.h and i didnt found anything wrong ... i added the complete CMakeList like i have it in the question can u have a look on it and maybe see whats missing ?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-05**:
Your `CMakeLists.txt` file does not look like any I have ever seen for a ROS1 package. You really need to find one from a package that actually compiles and use it as a reference for your own project.

**Comment by [Fxaxo](https://answers.ros.org/users/75761/fxaxo/) on 2021-07-06**:
oh okay i will search and keep u updated when i find the solution ! thank you ! @Mike Scheutzow

**Comment by [Fxaxo](https://answers.ros.org/users/75761/fxaxo/) on 2021-07-08**:
i found a CMakeLists.txt wich i copied and configured for my Project do this fit more in the regular CMakeLists ?

i added the new file in the question

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-08**:
That `CMakeLists.txt` still looks incomplete to me. Have you tried looking at any of the roscpp tutorials? For example, this one:

```
http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber
```

Make sure you get a clean build by deleting the top-level `devel` and `lib` directories in `catkin_ws` dir if you make big changes to `CMakeLists.txt`, or old broken stuff tends to get "remembered".

**Comment by [404RobotNotFound](https://answers.ros.org/users/46260/404robotnotfound/) on 2021-07-08**:
As a side note, you can highlight your text and use `Ctrl + k` to format it as code and make it a lot more readable and not get caught in markdown formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to create a valid `CMakeLists.txt` file. For an example, take a look at
http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [404RobotNotFound](https://answers.ros.org/users/46260/404robotnotfound/) on 2021-07-08**:
This is probably the more correct solution after you have dug deeper into the issue.
Even the code linked in the initial question (https://github.com/ros-drivers/um7) is a good enough example to follow